# Sideways Button Menu on Android

Tags: android, button, user-interface, layout, menu

I am attempting to make a button menu in Android that would scroll out sideways when a button is clicked, prompting the user to select from another set of choices (more buttons).

Here is a quick wireframe of what I wish to achieve:
[image]

So as you can see, clicking the button prompts another menu to scroll up. I understand that there are tools such as the [Context Menu](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#context-menu), and [Dialogs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html), but that is not what the client has requested. They have specifically asked for this kind of menu UI.

**Is this kind of menu UI possible in Android? Either by a System Library or custom creation? If the latter, how would I go about getting started?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use HorizontalListView for this, there are some good libraries you can use like this one: https://github.com/sephiroth74/HorizontalVariableListView. Just add this list next to the button, set its visibility parameter to 'invisible' and when user taps a button change it to 'visible'. Of course you can add some nice show and hide animations to make it look smooth and professional :)